# Using the Bloch Ansatz in the Stationary Schrödinger Equation to Derive Dynamical Diffraction Intensity Equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, schroedinger-equation, diffraction

I am working on deriving the intensity equations for the dynamical diffraction of neutrons following along with a paper by Hartmut Lemmel (Hartmut Lemmel. Dynamical diffraction of neutrons and transition from beam splitter to phase shifter case. Phys. Rev. B, 76:144305, Oct 2007).

The first task is to get the following equation for an infinite system of coupled equations

$$
\Biggl(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}|\vec{K}-\vec{H}|^2-E\Biggr)u_\vec{H}=-\sum_\vec{H^\prime}V_{\vec{H^\prime}-\vec{H}}u_\vec{H^\prime}
$$

I am trying to work out all the math myself so I am plugging in both
$$
\psi(\vec{r})=e^{i\vec{K}\vec{r}}\sum_{\vec{H}}u_{\vec{H}}e^{i\vec{H}\vec{r}}
$$
the Bloch ansatz and
$$
V(\vec{r})=\sum_\vec{H}V_\vec{H}e^{i\vec{H}\vec{r}}
$$
the potential for a periodic system into the stationary Schrödinger equation
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi(\vec{r})+V(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r})=E\psi(\vec{r})
$$
I took the Cartesian Laplacian and acted it on $\psi(\vec{r})$ with $\vec{r} = x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$, $\vec{K}=K_x\hat{x}+K_y\hat{y}+K_z\hat{z}$, and $\vec{H}=H_x\hat{x}+H_y\hat{y}+H_z\hat{z}$. Then plugged that expression back into the Schrodinger equation along with everything else and simplified. What I get is the following
$$
e^{i\vec{K}\vec{r}}\sum_\vec{H}\Biggl(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}|\vec{K}-\vec{H}|^2-E\Biggr)u_\vec{H}e^{i\vec{H\vec{r}}}=-\sum_\vec{H}V_\vec{H}e^{i\vec{H}\vec{r}}\Biggl(e^{i\vec{K}\vec{r}}\sum_{H^\prime}u_\vec{H^\prime}e^{i\vec{H^\prime}\vec{r}}\Biggr)
$$

I assume from here I am able to cancel the $e^{i\vec{K}\vec{r}}$ and $e^{i\vec{H}\vec{r}}$ on both sides in order to leave me with
$$
\sum_\vec{H}\Biggl(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}|\vec{K}-\vec{H}|^2-E\Biggr)u_\vec{H}=-\sum_\vec{H}V_\vec{H}\Biggl(\sum_{H^\prime}u_\vec{H^\prime}e^{i\vec{H^\prime}\vec{r}}\Biggr)
$$
I have never been that great at working with summations so if that is not allowed please do let me know. If it is, I am a little lost from here.

1. How does the sum over $\vec{H}$ on the left side go away?
2. How do we accomplish the change in the summation indices on the right side to get it to look like we want it to?
3. What happens to the $e^{i\vec{H^\prime}\vec{r}}$ in the second summation on the right side? How does that disappear?

I am thinking there are some physics explanations as to how you jump from the step I am at to the next, but it just isn't clear to me how this is accomplished or reasoned through. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are summing over $H$, so you cannot cancel the $\exp iHr$... Anyway, this exact calculation should be carried out in basically any (intro) solid state physics book. Have you consulted any of these, or checked some online lectures?

Comment: Perhaps a minor issue, but did you consider bold vector notation and an explicit dot-product symbol? Instead of $u_{\vec{H}}e^{i\vec{H}\vec{r}}$ that would give 
$u_{\bf H}\, e^{i{\bf H}\cdot{\bf r}}$, coded as `$u_{\bf H}\ e^{i{\bf H}\cdot{\bf r}}$.` (But of course you may have reasons to prefer your own choice...)